# Maven Jacoco Configuration - Exclude classes/packages from report not working

Tags: maven, configuration, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I have a maven multi-module project and I'm using jacoco-maven for code coverage reports. Some classes should not be reported, as they're Spring configuration and I'm not interested in them.

I have declared the maven-jacoco plugin as follow:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
<artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>0.7.2.201409121644</version>
<configuration>
    <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-ut</outputDirectory>
    <exclude>some.package.*</exclude>
    <exclude>**/*Config.*</exclude>
    <exclude>**/*Dev.*</exclude>
    <exclude>some/package/SomeClass.java</exclude>
</configuration>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <goals>
            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
    <execution>
        <id>report</id>
        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>report</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
    <execution>
        <id>post-unit-test</id>
        <phase>test</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>report</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

The problem is that when I execute `mvn clean verify` jacoco still reports classes that should have been excluded as my xml configuration points out. How can I configure it properly?

Answer (score 243, accepted):

Your XML is slightly wrong, you need to add any class exclusions within an excludes parent field, so your above configuration should look like the following as per the [Jacoco docs](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/report-mojo.html)

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.8</version>
    <configuration>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/*Config.*</exclude>
            <exclude>**/*Dev.*</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>jacoco-report</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The values of the exclude fields should be class paths (not package names) of the compiled classes relative to the directory target/classes/ using the standard wildcard syntax

```
*   Match zero or more characters
**  Match zero or more directories
?   Match a single character
```

You may also exclude a package and all of its children/subpackages this way:

```
<exclude>some/package/**/*</exclude>
```

This will exclude every class in `some.package`, as well as any children. For example, `some.package.child` wouldn't be included in the reports either.

I have tested and my report goal reports on a reduced number of classes using the above.

If you are then pushing this report into Sonar, you will then need to tell Sonar to exclude these classes in the display which can be done in the Sonar settings

Settings > General Settings > Exclusions > Code Coverage

[Sonar Docs](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus#NarrowingtheFocus-IgnoreCodeCoverage) explains it a bit more

Running your command above

```
mvn clean verify
```

Will show the classes have been excluded

No exclusions

```
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.4.201502262128:report (post-test) @ ** ---
[INFO] Analyzed bundle '**' with 37 classes
```

With exclusions

```
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.4.201502262128:report (post-test) @ ** ---
[INFO] Analyzed bundle '**' with 34 classes
```

Comment: I had to upgrade the Jacoco plugin from version 0.7.5 to 0.7.6 to get the exclude to be taken into account.

Comment: By the way. you'd have an idea on displaying my tests in the jacoco-it folder ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37485133/have-integration-tests-in-jacoco-it-directory

Comment: I wonder how to exclude, not source code classes, but test classes.

Comment: Great tip regarding Sonar. Easy to assume that JaCoCo exclusions will automagically propogate to Sonar (like I did).

Comment: If I exclude a file form jacoco it shows up in the coverage report with 0% coverage. So basically I get worse results compared to no exclude. Can this be fixed?

Comment: Remember to use slash between filenames and not dot. Also, file ending is .class and not .java.

Comment: If you have a report with 0% coverage you probably missed the reporting configuration.There should also be excludes section.

Comment: i'm using sonar-scanner with sonar-project prop file to capture jacoco report, but actually when i use this option in my pom to exclude some classes, the code coverage in sonar did not consider that, but in the build consider that why !!

Comment: It's important to understand the impact of ** and *. If you don't include ** and then it won't traverse into underlying directories. The * is a single character and should be used for file name purposes.

Comment: The folder structure also matters : for example : **/webapp/**/* will exclude all files under webapp directory. The "**" is for directory and "*" is for file. If you just have **/webapp/* then it won't exclude the folders under webapp folder.

Comment: Is it possible to exclude a whole bundle? I've got a target/classes folder w/ several subfolders w/ hundreds of .class files. Another issue is that some other bundles have subfolders w/ equal names, so it's even not appropriate to exclude on subfolder level in my case. So how can I exclude a folder which is a parent of target/classes?

Comment: After Git Hell comes Jacoco Hell :)

Comment: @AdamArold w/ Jacoco version 0.8.5 excluded stuff (bundles in my case) appear as "n/a" in report and do not affect the overall coverage %.

Comment: How to exclude a package from prepare-agent phase in plugin? `<exclude>some/package/**/*</exclude>` This excludes from report but not from Jacoco.exec file.

Answer (score 28):

Though Andrew already answered question with details , i am giving code how to exclude it in pom

```
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.7.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/*com/test/vaquar/khan/HealthChecker.class</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <!-- prepare agent for measuring integration tests -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>jacoco-initialize</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jacoco-site</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

**For Springboot application**

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                       <!-- Exclude class from test coverage -->
                        <exclude>**/*com/khan/vaquar/Application.class</exclude>
                        <!-- Exclude full package from test coverage -->
                        <exclude>**/*com/khan/vaquar/config/**</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: It seems the class path should be **without `.class` ending**, such as:

`<exclude>**/*com/test/vaquar/khan/HealthChecker</exclude>`

Comment: This removes the entire package from the report for me:     
 
 `<exclude>com/mycompany/mypackage/**/*</exclude>`

Comment: Why `**/*com` and not just `**/com` ?

Comment: @JimTough exactly how to remove package from exec file only and not from report

Answer (score 6):

you can configure the coverage exclusion in the sonar properties, outside of the configuration of the jacoco plugin:

```
...
<properties>
    ....
    <sonar.exclusions>
        **/generated/**/*,
        **/model/**/*
    </sonar.exclusions>
    <sonar.test.exclusions>
        src/test/**/*
    </sonar.test.exclusions>
    ....
    <sonar.java.coveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
    <sonar.jacoco.reportPath>${project.basedir}/../target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>
    <sonar.coverage.exclusions>
        **/generated/**/*,
        **/model/**/*
    </sonar.coverage.exclusions>
    <jacoco.version>0.7.5.201505241946</jacoco.version>
    ....
</properties>
....
```

and remember to remove the exclusion settings from the plugin

Answer (score 6):

Some Examples from the SonarQube Docs:
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Another solution:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.5.201505241946</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>default-report</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>default-check</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <rules>
                    <rule implementation="org.jacoco.maven.RuleConfiguration">
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>com.mypackage1</exclude
                            <exclude>com.mypackage2</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                        <element>PACKAGE</element>
                        <limits>
                            <limit implementation="org.jacoco.report.check.Limit">
                                <counter>COMPLEXITY</counter>
                                <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                <minimum>0.85</minimum>
                            </limit>
                        </limits>
                    </rule>
                </rules>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Please note that, we are using `"<element>PACKAGE</element>"` in the configuration which then helps us to exclude at package level.

Comment: I am using jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.9. With your solution, it calculates the results correctly. However, all clases in project appear in the jacoco report (index.html). Is it possible to show in the report just what the plugin has analyzed in order to have the real value of covered ratio?

Answer (score 4):

Use sonar.coverage.exclusions property.

```
mvn clean install -Dsonar.coverage.exclusions=**/*ToBeExcluded.java
```

This should exclude the classes from coverage calculation.

Answer (score 4):

**This Work Like a charm with Spring Boot 2.5.3   and Jacoco 0.8.4 ^_^**

```
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <destFile>${basedir}/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-unit.exec</destFile>
                    <dataFile>${basedir}/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-unit.exec</dataFile>
                    <output>file</output>
                    <append>true</append>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/*com/example/Application.class</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/*com/example/modal*/**</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/*com/example/dto*/**</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/*com/example/mapper*/**</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jacoco-report</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/34

These are the different notations for classes we have:

- VM Name: java/util/Map$Entry
- Java Name: java.util.Map$Entry File
- Name: java/util/Map$Entry.class

**Agent Parameters, Ant tasks and Maven prepare-agent goal**

- includes: Java Name (VM Name also works)
- excludes: Java Name (VM Name also works)
- exclclassloader: Java Name

These specifications allow wildcards * and ?, where * wildcards any number of characters, even multiple nested folders.

**Maven report goal**

- includes: File Name
- excludes: File Name

These specs allow Ant Filespec like wildcards *, ** and ?, where * wildcards parts of a single path element only.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working sample in `pom.xml` file.

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${jacoco.version}</version>


        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>prepare-agent</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>post-unit-test</id>
                <phase>test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>report</goal>
                </goals>

            </execution>

            <execution>
                <id>default-check</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>check</goal>
                </goals>

            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <dataFile>target/jacoco.exec</dataFile>
            <!-- Sets the output directory for the code coverage report. -->
            <outputDirectory>target/jacoco-ut</outputDirectory>
            <rules>
                <rule implementation="org.jacoco.maven.RuleConfiguration">
                    <element>PACKAGE</element>
                    <limits>
                        <limit implementation="org.jacoco.report.check.Limit">
                            <counter>COMPLEXITY</counter>
                            <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                            <minimum>0.00</minimum>
                        </limit>
                    </limits>
                </rule>
            </rules>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>com/pfj/fleet/dao/model/**/*</exclude>
            </excludes>
            <systemPropertyVariables>

                <jacoco-agent.destfile>target/jacoco.exec</jacoco-agent.destfile>
            </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```