# How to exclude a class from Jacoco coverage?

Tags: maven, jenkins, jacoco, cobertura, jacoco-maven-plugin

I want to use Jacoco in a way so that it excludes a `Sample.java class` from the overall coverage. To achieve that I have included `<exclude>` within `prepare-agent` goal in maven pom.xml

Jacoco plugin:

```
                <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.1.201405082137</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Surefire plugin:

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*Sample.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

properties section:

```
    <properties>
    <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=ISO-8859-1</argLine>
</properties>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven Jacoco Configuration - Exclude classes/packages from report not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27799419/maven-jacoco-configuration-exclude-classes-packages-from-report-not-working)

Comment: You aren't setting the configuration for the right plugin. The exclusion should be for `jacoco-maven-plugin` but you don't have any.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the right way to configure excludes/includes for JaCoCo:

```
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.1.201405082137</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*Sample.class</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

For more details, you can go through this documentation:
http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/prepare-agent-mojo.html

Comment: Probably best not to configure the `prepare-agent` goal. From the docs: Except for performance optimization or technical corner cases this option is normally not required. If you want to exclude classes from the report please configure the `report` goal accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my solution, please note the exclude class pattern is `class.path.className`.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>check</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
            <haltOnFailure>true</haltOnFailure>
            <rules>
                <rule>
                    <element>CLASS</element>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>com.example.className</exclude>
                        <exclude>com.example.config.*</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                    <limits>
                        <limit>
                            <counter>LINE</counter>
                            <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                            <minimum>0.80</minimum>
                        </limit>
                    </limits>
                </rule>
            </rules>
            </configuration>
         </execution>
     </executions>
 </plugin>
```

And for the config detail, please check [this doco](https://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/check-mojo.html), hope it helps.