# How can I filter out packages from the JaCoCo Maven scope?

Tags: java, maven, eclemma, jacoco-maven-plugin

I'm working on code coverage for a Java library. It's a SOAP/REST client.  The client has several packages **dataTypes.generated.** for the generated types for connecting to the server side.  For working with the client there is a translation layer to some more common types just in the **dataTypes** package, that I also want to filter out of coverage.  However, I do have some some utility classes in **dataTypes.helpers** that I want to keep included.

I've tried:

```
  <plugin>
      <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
      <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>0.7.4.201502262128</version>
      <configuration>
       <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco.exec</dataFile>
       <destFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco.exec</destFile>
       <excludes>
         <exclude>**/dataTypes/*.*</exclude>
         <exclude>**/generated/*</exclude>
         <exclude>**/generated/**</exclude> -->
       </excludes>
       <includes>
         <include>**/dataTypes/helpers/*</include>
       </includes>
   </plugin>
```

however, That didn't remove it from coverage.
In EclEmma I then set:

*Includes:*    `*:**/dataTypes/helpers/*`
*Excludes:*    `**/dataTypes/*:**/generated/*`

That didn't work either. It actually seemed to break something in *EclEmma* and code coverage didn't display at all.

I had it working at one point.

I used *Excludes:* but that doesn't remove code from coverage, it just forces coverage to 0%, I'd just rather not see it in the report at all.  How can I do that?

Comment: where did you put those excludes statement? It apply the inclusion/exclusion in the prepare-agent goal defined by the jacoco plugin

Comment: @drgn I've updated the question with the complete plugin section for the `jacoco-maven-plugin`

Comment: this might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27799419/maven-jacoco-configuration-exclude-classes-packages-from-report-not-working - it does not look so bad. maybe the exclusion patterns dont work like that. often multiple ** are not recognized. maybe "*/**/generated/*" (and removing the second one so no pattern contains two "**")? Try and error it is :/

Comment: @Raystorm did you solve the issue since then?

Comment: @A. Di Matteo I've been unable to get filtering to work from maven. I think it may be unsupported. I have gotten includes/excludes working but it's been unstable. I'd really like to get maven and EclEmma synced but so far I haven't had much luck.