# Have integration tests in jacoco-it directory

Tags: maven, integration-testing, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I have integration tests and they are executed fine, but Jacoco considers them as unit tests. How to tell Jacoco to see them as integration tests and display their graph coverage, not in the jacoco-ut directory, but it the jacoco-it directory ?

Here in the Maven configuration:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.18.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <argLine>${surefireArgLine}</argLine>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>**/it/java/*.java</exclude>
      </excludes>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.10</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>add-test-source</id>
        <phase>process-test-sources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>add-test-source</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <sources>
            <source>src/it/java</source>
          </sources>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>add-test-resource</id>
        <phase>generate-test-resources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>add-test-resource</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <resources>
            <resource>
              <directory>src/it/resources</directory>
            </resource>
          </resources>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>add-it-resources</id>
        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>copy-resources</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/it-classes</outputDirectory>
          <resources>
            <resource>
              <directory>src/it/resources</directory>
            </resource>
          </resources>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <argLine>${failsafeArgLine}</argLine>
      <testSourceDirectory>src/it/java</testSourceDirectory>
      <testClassesDirectory>${project.build.directory}/it-classes</testClassesDirectory>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.6.201602180812</version>
    <configuration>
      <skip>${maven.test.skip}</skip>
      <output>file</output>
      <append>true</append>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>**/config/*</exclude>
        <exclude>**/dialect/*</exclude>
      </excludes>
    </configuration>        
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>pre-unit-test</id>
        <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <destFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</destFile>
          <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
          <includes><include>**/ut/*</include></includes>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>post-unit-test</id>
        <phase>test</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>report</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</dataFile>
          <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-ut</outputDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>pre-integration-test</id>
        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>prepare-agent-integration</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <destFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-it.exec</destFile>
          <propertyName>failsafeArgLine</propertyName>
          <includes><include>**/it/*</include></includes>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>post-integration-test</id>
        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>report-integration</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-it.exec</dataFile>
          <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-it</outputDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

UPDATE: I was missing this bit in the maven-failsafe-plugin plugin:

```
<executions>
  <execution>       
    <goals>                       
      <goal>integration-test</goal>               
    </goals>                                                  
  </execution>                                                          
</executions>
```

After having added it as in:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <argLine>${failsafeArgLine}</argLine>
      <includes>
        <include>**/it/**</include>
      </includes>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>       
        <goals>                       
          <goal>integration-test</goal>               
        </goals>                                                  
      </execution>                                                          
    </executions>                                                                   
  </plugin>
```

the integration tests report shows the integration tests.

The final full configuration is:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.18.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <argLine>${surefireArgLine}</argLine>
      <includes>
        <include>**/ut/**</include>
      </includes>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.10</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>add-test-source</id>
        <phase>process-test-sources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>add-test-source</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <sources>
            <source>src/it/java</source>
          </sources>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>add-test-resource</id>
        <phase>generate-test-resources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>add-test-resource</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <resources>
            <resource>
              <directory>src/it/resources</directory>
            </resource>
          </resources>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <argLine>${failsafeArgLine}</argLine>
      <includes>
        <include>**/it/**</include>
      </includes>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>integration-test</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.6.201602180812</version>
    <configuration>
      <skip>${maven.test.skip}</skip>
      <output>file</output>
      <append>true</append>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>**/config/*</exclude>
        <exclude>**/dialect/*</exclude>
      </excludes>
    </configuration>        
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>pre-unit-test</id>
        <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <destFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</destFile>
          <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>post-unit-test</id>
        <phase>test</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>report</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</dataFile>
          <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-ut</outputDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>pre-integration-test</id>
        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>prepare-agent-integration</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <destFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-it.exec</destFile>
          <propertyName>failsafeArgLine</propertyName>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>post-integration-test</id>
        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>report-integration</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-it.exec</dataFile>
          <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-it</outputDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstood the pattern for the include tag of maven-failsafe-plugin. The pattern is used for the package name of the classes within the test classpath (see also https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html).

The build-helper-maven-plugin includes all classes in `src/it/java` to the test classpath. Then the pattern of include tag in both test plugins (surefire, failsafe) filters the classes within this test classpath. These filtered classes are executed by the test plugins.

So the workflow is

1. Build-Helper-Plugin extends the set of the test classes that have to be compiled and executed. Therefore the source directive is used.  The path location defined in this source directive is related to the Maven project path.
2. Compiler Plugin compiles the java classes.
3. Jacoco-Plugin should measure the coverage in the production classes with unit tests. Therefore, the normal agent has to be prepared before the tests are executed. You can specify which production code should be included or excluded in the coverage measurment (include/exclude directive). The pattern in these directives are package-based (shlashes are used instead of dots).
4. Surefire-Plugin executes the tests whose full-qualified class name match the pattern of the include directive. The pattern uses slashes instead of dots.
5. Now the Jacoco-Plugin should measure the coverage in the production classes with integration tests. Therefore, the integration agent has to be prepared before the tests are executed. And again,  you can specify which production code should be included or excluded in the coverage measurment (include/exclude directive). The pattern in these directives are package-based (shlashes are used instead of dots).
6. The same for the Failsafe-Plugin. It executes the tests whose full-qualified class name match the pattern of the include directive. The pattern uses slashes instead of dots.

Comment: I understand I must use a path pattern and not a package pattern. Is that right ? Are you saying all classes are mix together in the very same directory ? There is no way then to differentiate them with a sub directory name ? Only a class name suffix, like IT, can help here ?

Comment: No, the other way around. You have to use a package pattern. After compiling, all compiled classes from src/it/java and src/test/java are under target/test-classes (the test-classpath). Then the surefire/failsafe plugin executes the classes described by the pattern in the include tag. Therefore, your approach using a class name suffix will help. BTW check the default suffix of the failsafe plugin (http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#includes) to reduce the configuration.

Comment: I'm still confused as the doc shows path like includes. The slash means path like. The dot means package like. I tried this config: <configuration>
              <destFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-it.exec</destFile>
              <propertyName>failsafeArgLine</propertyName>
              <includes>
                <include>*.it.*</include>
              </includes>
            </configuration> and <include>*/it/*</include> but these two configs didn't include anything. I have my integration tests in an it/ folder. You'd know how to express that as an include ?

Comment: For example, you have two classes named com.example.integrationtest.ATest and com.example.unittest.BTest. ATest.java is located in src/it/java (means failsafe should execute it) and BTest.java is located under src/test/java (means surefire should execute it). Then the include pattern for failsafe is <include>*/integration/*</include> and the pattern for surefire is <include>*/unittest/*</include>. It is a pattern for package, but they use slashes instead of dots .

Comment: There must be something else in my configuration that stands in the way. This include directive is to filter the source classes under test or the test classes ?

Comment: If using the build-helper-maven-plugin plugin, then I wonder if it makes sense to have a pre-integration-test and post-integration-test executions in the jacoco plugin.

Comment: The include directive of surefire and failsafe are for the test classes. Please post an example of the full qualified name of a test classes. You need the pre/post-integration-test executions for the jacoco plugin, because failsafe's integration goal is binded on the integration phase.

Comment: When you say the include directives are for the test classes, you mean the ones in the execution configurations ? Because the one is the parent configuration of the Jacoco plugin, `<exclude>**/config/*</exclude <exclude>**/dialect/*</exclude>` exclude the application code and not the tests. If you look at my configuration, the Jacoco plugin configuration is already binding to the pre and post integration phases, or is it ?

Comment: Your binding is correct, but the pattern in the include directive of the jacoco plugin has to relate to the production code. Maybe the pattern is wrong. I have extended my answer by explaining the workflow with all plugins.Perhaps it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the effort Sandra. I can say the pattern is not wrong. I had even removed it altogether to make sure it was not at fault. Maybe you have a working Maven config doing what I'm trying to do that I could use ? Or, since what I'm trying to do is quite standard, unit tests under test/ and integration tests under it/ with two Jacoco reports, maybe you can try a copy paste of my Maven configuration ?

Comment: I have checked and corrected your configuration by means of an exemplary project. Follow the commits to see my steps. https://github.com/sparsick/jacoco-coverage-report-maven

Comment: The example project still has the same 'issues' I have with mine, that is: 1- it needs the integration test class to be suffixed with IT as in BClassIT when I'd like to have it suffixed with Test as in BClassTest (I use the includes and excludes for this) and 2- it counts the integration test in the unit test report (removing the BClassIT test halved the ut coverage report) when I want to count only unit tests in the unit test coverage report.

Comment: Sorry for my late answer. About 1) I adjusted the configuration so that the kind of tests is dependent by the package name. But I think it's a good approach. About 2) I couldn't reproduce your observation. Therefore, I add my generated jacoco reports into the report folder. Ensure that you call mvn clean install for cleaning the target folder before the new report is generated.

Comment: No worries Sandra and thank you for the effort. Indeed your project now behaves exactly as you say and as I was looking for. I shall try fixing my pom.xml file to reflect this configuration in my own project.

Comment: In my last comment it should mean "it's *not* a good approach". The reason is that you can have trouble with your structure if you tests package-protected classes. I will prefer the suffix way.