# It is possible to exclude java classes from the coverage of the tests?

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, junit

I wanted to know if with Spring Boot and Eclipse it is possible to configure something so that in the% of the project coverage it does not take into account the coverage of certain classes.

Answer (score 0):

```
  you are using jacoco plugin u can use like below 
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
      <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>${jacoco.mavenplugin.version}</version>
      <configuration>
          <excludes>
               <exclude>some/package/**/*</exclude>
          </excludes>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
          ...
      </executions>
    </plugin>
```

please refer below

[Maven Jacoco Configuration - Exclude classes/packages from report not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27799419/maven-jacoco-configuration-exclude-classes-packages-from-report-not-working)

Comment: I have this pachage: test.my.project.config How would it be to exclude the .config package

Comment: <exclude>test.my.project.config/**/*</exclude>