# Can't exclude classes and packages from Jacoco test coverage report (IntelliJ)

Tags: java, maven, user-interface, intellij-idea, jacoco

I can't get over the certain problem
My sudoku app consist of the model classes responsible for app logic (they are in **model package**) and gui classes responsible for displaying sudokuBoard form on the screen (they are in **gui package**).
I want to **exclude gui package** classes from **Jacoco test coverage report** but after trying several solutions it is still being shown there. I use Maven for my project and IntelliJ-Idea for IDE.
I was trying to add both only classes and the package itself to pom.xml exclude section in jacoco plugin.

Maybe you solved similar problems and can give me any advice?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27799419/maven-jacoco-configuration-exclude-classes-packages-from-report-not-working

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not help.

Comment: are you adding the excludes in execution/configuration and that everything is in pluginManagement